# SignalR Cookie Authentication Not Working In Blazor Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, blazor, signalr-hub

Here I have simple private chat application in blazor server signalR where user logins, addfriend and chat with that friend.
For login I have used `AspNetCore.Identity`.
Now, the problem is that the application works perfectly fine in local machine but as I run application in `ngrok()` there is an error saying
 `Error: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).`
ngrok is a cross-platform application that enables developers to expose a local development server to the Internet.
The software makes locally-hosted web server appear to be hosted on a subdomain of ngrok.com, meaning that no public IP or domain name on the local machine is needed  
Below is what have done to authenticate user to signlar hub

In Host.cshtml

```
@{
 var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Identity.Application"];    
}
<body>
 @* Pass the captured Cookie to the App component as a paramter*@

 <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" param-Cookie="cookie" />
</body>
```

In App.razor

```
@inject CookiesProvider CookiesProvider

@* code omitted here... *@

@code{

   [Parameter]
   public string Cookie { get; set; }

   protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {
     // Pass the Cookie parameter to the CookiesProvider service
     // which is to be injected into the Chat component, and then 
     // passed to the Hub via the hub connection builder

        CookiesProvider.Cookie = Cookie;

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

CookiesProvider.cs

```
public class CookiesProvider
{
    public string Cookie { get; set; }
}
```

In webchat.razor

```
@attribute [Authorize]

@* code omitted here... *@

@code{
       protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
       {
         var container = new CookieContainer();
         var cookie = new Cookie() 
         {
             Name = ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application", 
             Domain = "localhost",
             Value = CookiesProvider.Cookie
         };

         container.Add(cookie);

         hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
         .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/chathub"), options => 
          {
              // Pass the security cookie to the Hub. 

                 options.Cookies = container; 
          }).Build();

          await hubConnection.StartAsync();
       }

  }
```

In hub

```
[Authorize()]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{

}
```

Comment: Did you post this question in Github ?

Comment: The best suggestion I can offer you right now is either remove the Domain property or provide it different values and see what happens.

Comment: Did you see this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidProthero.NgrokExtensions

Comment: https://ngrok.com/docs

Comment: @enet changing domain property worked for me thank you

Comment: I have it working. I am also setting the Headers. I posted a solution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1160923/solution-custom-signalr-endpoints-(hubs)-in-a-blaz